# Winforms Progress Bar Visible true false

Tags: c#, winforms

My code that works:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

If I add something for the computer to do, as seen in the following code example, the computer does not show the progress bar until it's done doing the computation. What I want it to do is show the progress bar first, then do the computation, then on some other event I want to hide the progress bar. Why can't I do it this way?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    FindPrimeNumber(50000);
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

The requested FindPrimeNumber code:

```
public int FindPrimeNumber(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    int a = 2;
    while (count < n)
    {
        int b = 2;
        int prime = 1;// to check if found a prime
        while (b * b <= a)
        {
            if (a % b == 0)
            {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
            b++;
        }
        if (prime > 0)
            count++;
        a++;
    }
    return (--a);
}
```

the FindPrimeNumber code is just something to make the computer do a task for a while, so I can test to see if my progress bar is going to show.

Comment: That's pretty basic, your UI thread can animate the progressbar *or* it can find a prime.  It cannot do both.  Use a Task or BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Can you please show the code for `FindPrimeNumber` (and any other code that is relevant to what you're trying to do)?

Comment: I see your code, thank you, but how are you proposing to update your progress bar?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am not wanting to update the progress bar. I am just wanting to show a marquee style progress bar because it is not that long of a process. I think an update to the progress bar could be implemented if someone needed to, but I'm not going there at this time.

Comment: @McGrew - Oh, so you just want the progress bar to effectively animate during the computation (aka "I'm busy"), but not reflect the actual progress. Is that right?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yes, just need to show "I'm busy" type of thing. I figured it out with a BackgroundWorker. Please see the answer I posted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In this example, a user enters a 5 digit number in a text box, then a progress bar shows up on the form as it is processing the number in a math function, then the result is put into a second text box and the progress bar goes away.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.TextLength == 5)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        int textFromTextBox1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(textFromTextBox1);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = FindPrimeNumber((int)e.Argument);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Note: This example does not handle all exceptions, but it works great. As you can probably see in the code I am passing a value into the BackgroundWorker which gets passed into the FindPrimeNumber method, then I am retrieving the result out of the BackgroundWorker.

More notes for newbies:

I have the BackgroundWorker property WorkerSupportsCancellation set to True.

In WinForms, after dropping the BackgroundWorker onto the form, when you double click it, it will generate the DoWorkEventHandler for you, then in the Solution Explorer go to the Events and double click on RunWorkerCompleted so it can generated that for you as well. Otherwise, you will have to do a lot of manual code entry.