# C# winforms, progress bar will freeze on button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have my progress bar in my form as 'Marquee' style so it should continuously run, however when I click my button so that the progress will appear, it is froze and does not move, however if I don't hide the progressbar at the start it will run normally.

I only want it to appear when the button is clicked though, any ideas around this?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar1.Hide();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Show();
        DrawingHandler MyDrawingHandler = new DrawingHandler();
        MyDrawingHandler.GetConnectionStatus();
            try
            {
                Operation.RunMacro("shaftCheck.cs");
                DrawingEnumerator SelectedDrawings = MyDrawingHandler.GetDrawingSelector().GetSelected();
                if (SelectedDrawings.GetSize() == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error, no drawings to export.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Operation.RunMacro("ExportShaft2.cs");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you are doing some kind of slow operation on the UI thread.

There is in most cases only one UI thread, this is the only thread allowed to update the UI, and this can only do one thing at a time. If you are using the UI thread to do some kind of processing it cannot do other things, like updating your UI.

The solution is to put all processing intensive operation on a background thread. For example with [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0). But you will need to ensure any called code does not trigger any UI updates.

If you just have a progress bar as part of the dialog it is fairly easy. But it results in the user being able to do other things while you are doing the processing, so you need to be super-careful that all your code is thread safe.

A safer option is usually to show a modal dialog that prevents the user from doing anything else. This greatly reduces the risk of thread safety issues. Typically it would look something like this:

```
            var progressForm = new MyProgressForm();
            Task.Run(MyWorkerMethod)
                .ContinueWith(t => progressForm.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            progressForm .ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there another property in the progressbar that is a better fit for your needs. [Winforms Progress Bar Visible true false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121147/winforms-progress-bar-visible-true-false) in this post it looks like you can change the visibility with the Visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has only one thread that may update the UI. If you keep this thread busy doing other things, then your UI won't be updated, nor will it respond to operator input.

```
void LongRunningMethod() {...}

private void OnButton1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
    this.LongRunningMethod();
    this.progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

While LongRunningMethod is being executed, the UI won't respond: the progressbar is not updated, the UI does not respond to user input.

There are two often used methods to solve this.

- Old fashioned: use a [BackGroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-6.0), and let this BackGroundWorker do the LongRunningMethod. The BackGroundWorker sends events when it is finished. You can use that event to hide the progressBar again.
- Modern: use async-await. Let a separate Task do the LongRunningMethod.

I won't discuss the BackGroundWorker. If you understand event handling, you will get the gist of it. I'll describe async-await instead.

What really helped me to understand async-await was [this interview with Eric Lippert](https://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1). Search somewhere in the middle for async await.

In this interview Eric Lippert compares async-await with a cook making breakfast. Whenever the cook has to wait for something, like a kettle of water to boil, he doesn't wait idly, no, he looks around to see if he can do something else instead, like insert bread in the toaster. He doesn't wait for the bread to be toasted, he starts scrambling eggs. Later he returns to the boiling water to make tea, or to the toaster to get the toasted bread.

Async-await is similar: whenever your thread has to wait for another process to finish, like writing a file, reading from a database or from the internet, you can let the thread wait idly until the other process completed the task. You could also let the thread do other things, like updating the progressbar and listening to user input. This is called async-await.

Whenever your thread sees an await, it does not wait idly, but it goes up the call stack and execute the code until the caller has an await, up the call stack again and execute the code until the thread sees an await, etc.

Later, when the file-write is finished, or the database data is fetched, or the internet data is downloaded, the thread (or to be precise: any thread from the thread pool) will execute the code after the await.

To be able to use async-await, do the following:

- Whenever your program has to wait for another lengthy process, like the examples that I gave above, find the async version of the process: WriteAsync / ReadAsync etc
- Define your method async. It is common usage to terminate the identifier of the method with Async: ReadFileAsync, GetProductsAsync, etc. This will make it possible to also have a non-async version: ReadFile, GetProducts.
- Return `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResult`; return `Task` instead of `void`.
- There is one exception to this rule: event handlers always return `void`: no one can await for the result of an event handler
- Inside the async method call the WriteAsync / ReadAsync etc. Don't await until you need the results of the async action. await before your async method returns
- If the return is `Task<TResult>`, the result of the await is `TResult`. If you await `Task`, the return is void.

So if you need to read lines of text from a file:

```
private async Task<List<string>> ReadFileAsync(string fileName)
{
    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        string line = await textReader.ReadLineAsync();
        while (line != null)
        {
            // a line has been read, add it to the lines, and read the next
            lines.Add(line);
            line = await textReader.ReadLineAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

So if the operator presses a button to read the file and to process the read lines async:

```
private async Task ProcessLinesAsync(IEnumerable<string> linesToProcess) {...}

private async Task ReadAndProcessFileAsync()
{
    string fileName = this.GetFileName();
    List<string> lines = await this.ReadFileAsync(fileName);
    await this.ProcessLinesAsync(lines);
}

private async void OnButton1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ShowProgressBar();
    await this.ReadAndProcessFileAsync();
    this.HideProgressBar();
}
```

Note that the event handler returns `void` instead of `Task`.

ShowProgressBar is a method that will initialize the progressBar before showing it using `this.progressBar1.Visible = true;`.

### Use other thread to do lengthy calculations

Until now, the UI thread had to wait for another process to finish. Async-await can also be used if you need to do some length calculations while keeping the UI responsive. Use `Task.Run` to let one of the available threads in the thread pool do the lengthy calculations. Wait for it when you need the results:

```
private MyResult DoLengthyCalculations()
{
    // Do your lengthy calculations here:
    DrawingHandler MyDrawingHandler = new DrawingHandler();
    MyDrawingHandler.GetConnectionStatus();
        try
        {
            Operation.RunMacro("shaftCheck.cs");
            // etc
}

private async Task<MyResult> DoLengthyCalculationsAsync()
{
    MyResult result = await Task.Run( () => DoLengthyCalculations();
    return result;
}
```

By the way: this is an example where you have an async and a non-async method: the caller can decide which one he wants to use.

The event handler:

```
private async void OnButton1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ShowProgressBar();
    await this.DoLengthyCalculationsAsync();
    this.HideProgressBar();
}
```

### Continue processing after the other task started

If you can do something useful instead of awaiting for the task to finish, don't await yet. Await as late as possible: only when you need the result, and before returning.

```
async Task DoMyWorkAsync()
{
    // start reading the file. Don't await, while the file is being read,
    // you can do other things:
    Task<List<string>> taskReadFile = this.ReadFileAsync();

    // because you didn't await, you are free to do something else as soon as
    // the thread sees an await:
    this.DoSomethingElse();

    // you can even start a second task:
    Task<MyResult> taskLengthyCalculations = this.DoLengthyCalculationsAsync();

    // as soon as you need the results, await for it:
    List<string>> readLines = await taskReadFile;
    this.ProcessReadLines(readLines);
    ...
```

If you want: wait for both tasks to finish:

```
    Task[] allTasks = new Task[] {taskReadFile, taskLengthyCalculations};
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

    // you can access the return value using property Result:
    List<string>> readLines = taskReadFile.Result;
    MyResult lengthyCalculationsResult = taskLengthyCalculations.Result;
    this.Process(readLines, lengthyCalculationsResult);
```